# Is there a way to append FormData keys/values from an object in Angular?

Tags: php, angular

I have a simple Object that I define in my Angular class like this:

```
  form_data = {
    info: {
      name: "",
      address: "",
      city: "",
      state: "",
      zip: "",
    }
  }
```

I am trying to setup a new method to build my FormData before it is submitted to my backend service, however, it does not appear that the logic is working. I am trying to assign the data like such:

```
const formData = new FormData();
for (let i in this.form_data.info) {
  formData.append(i,this.form_data.info[i]);
}
this.api.submitData(formData).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

My api service is relatively simple:

```
 submitData(data) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/upload.php', {data: data}).pipe(
      map(response => {
        return response;
      })
    );
  }
```

And then my backend service (for now) is just looking to make sure the data is submitted:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' ) {

$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$post_data = json_decode($request_body, true);

echo json_encode($post_data);

}
```

However, each time I test to submit the form, everything is blank, and I am get back in my console is:

```
"data": []
```

Any thoughts on why I am unable to send the formData to my backend service? Am I setting something up incorrectly on the front end side?

Answer (score 0):

First of all see your browser's network tab what data is being send to backend and then try this way,

```
this.http.post(this.baseUrl + '/upload.php', data)
```

Comment: It's actually from a hybrid app (which is originally why I had Ionic4 tagged), but this is what is showing as the request data to the backend service as a bunch of `Content-Disposition: form-data;` with the field name, like this: `------WebKitFormBoundaryLSQRrmQ9tCRBJTjA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Test Name
------WebKitFormBoundaryLSQRrmQ9tCRBJTjA`

Comment: Is there any issue in this? you can assign data to any variable like this `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);` and then you can user $data ["name"] or $data ["address"] etc where you want.

Comment: Yes, the `$data` is always empty, no matter what data is passed. It is always returning `null` if I try and do a `echo json_encode($data);`.